# Array and dictionary, what's the correct syntax of loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, dictionary

I have a problem with loop in `array dictionary`. I need something like this. How to check if item of string array is equal item of `messagesDictionary`:

```
var stringArray = ["first","second","third"]
var messagesDictionary = [["first": 50],["second": 60],["third": 70]]

    for item in stringArray {
        for itemDic in messagesDictionary {
            if item == itemDic[key] { // this 'itemDic[key]' wrong

            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct syntax of this loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  You've got an array of dictionaries which you are looping through.  Are you trying to see if a specific value exists for some key?  Or are you trying to loop through each individual dictionary as well?

Comment: you need to iterate each dictionary in your messagesDictionary `for (key, value) in itemDic {`

Answer (score 2):

Iterate like this instead:

```
let stringArray:[String]  = ["first","second","third"]
let messagesDictionary: [[String: Any]] = [["first": 50],["second": 60],["third": 70]]
for item in stringArray {
    for itemDic in messagesDictionary {
        for (key, value) in itemDic {
            if item == key {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried. I get: "Expression type '[[String:Int]]' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Great @DenisWindover. You should consider accepting the answer so that others can benefit from it in the future. Just click the checkmark below the votes in my answer.